# DbUpdateConcurrencyException firing not where I thought it would

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, concurrency, entity

I'm just looking for some clarification to make sure I'm not missing something.  I have a Unit Test around EF 6.1 ConcurrencyChecking and I'm hoping someone can explain what I'm missing.

Here is my test:

```
    [TestMethod()]
    [TestCategory("DataBound")]
    [ExpectedException(typeof(DbUpdateConcurrencyException))]
    public async Task AccessListConcurrencyCheckTest()
    {
        //Add record to DB for test
        MyDBContext context1 = new MyDBContext();
        AccessListDAO accessListDAO1 = new AccessListDAO(context1);
        AccessList accessList = await accessList1.AddAccessList(accessList);

        //First request get newly added record
        AccessList accessList1 = await accessListDAO1.GetAccessList(accessList.AccessListId);

        //Second request get newly added record
        MyDBContext context2 = new MyDBContext ();
        AccessListDAO accessListDAO2 = new AccessListDAO(context2);
        AccessList accessList2 = await accessListDAO2.GetAccessList(accessList.AccessListId);

        accessList1.Description = "Updated by Request 1";
        await accessListDAO1.UpdateAccessList(accessList1);  //Exception happening here

        //If I uncomment the Delete Below and comment out the Update above, the test works as expected
        //await accessListDAORequest1.DeleteAccessList(testRecordRequest1.AccessListId);

        accessList2.Description = "Updated by Request 2";
        await accessListDAO2.UpdateAccessList(testRecordRequest2); //I would have expected exception here.
    }
```

As noted above, I would have expected the exception to occur on the 2nd Update given that the only thing that happened between the 1st get and the 1st update is another get, which should not have resulted in a data change.  Any help on connect these dots would be appreciated.

**UPDATE:** The plot thickens, I replaced the first Update with a Delete and the test operates as I expected.  Upon further review I've noticed that the millisecond/ticks property of the modified date is coming back as different than what is stored in the database.  If the Database has 2014-10-27 13:57:17.587 accessList1 on its return is coming back with the millisecond field being 588 or 5881995 and accessList2 is being set as 5870000.  If I step into the actually Update method if the find record in there is coming up with a value that sometimes matches one of the other 2 or it's own.  It would appear that the millisecond value is not coming back as a reliable value.  We are using a SQL backend.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new MyDBContext instance for the first "Get" instead of using the one created for the "Add" seemed to do the trick and resolve the issue.  I'm still now sure why this was an issue given the record being pulled from the table was never in any state of flux prior to the update statements.